# How to properly design of SQL query to achieve most optimal row output

Tags: mysql, sql

How to properly design a SQL query code to achieve most optimal row output:

select (top 3) C1 from Table where ...... (for given input c2 to c9)

Suppose there is one table which has 9 (data is percentages values) columns

Imagine Table has millions of rows.

```
     C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6   C7   C8   C9
     ==========================================
     0.1  0.9  0.4  0.7  0.7  0.3  0.5  0.8  0.9  R1
     0.6  0.7  0.3  0.5  0.8  0.9  0.1  0.9  0.4  R2
     0.1  0.9  0.4  0.7  0.7  0.3  0.5  0.8  0.9  R3
     0.1  0.7  0.3  0.5  0.8  0.9  0.3  0.5  0.8  R4
     0.7  0.7  0.9  0.1  0.9  0.4  0.2  0.2  0.2  R5
     0.7  0.7  0.3  0.5  0.8  0.9  0.4  0.7  0.2  R6
```

Result would be top 3 C1 values where the sum of absolute difference for each column value is minimal for give input of C2... to C9.

For example if input is C2=0.7, C3=0.3, C4=0.6, C5=0.8 C6=0.9 C7=0.3 C8=0.9 C9=0.2 then

Top 3 C1 values returned by SQL query should be:

```
     Result1 is 0.7 (as result was 0.4 from R6)
     Result2 is 0.6 (as result was 0.5 from R2)
     Result3 is 0.7 (as result was 2.5 from R5)
```

Calculations are explained below:

```
           C2=0.7    C3=0.3    C4=0.6    C5=0.8    C6=0.9    C7=0.3    C8=0.9    C9=0.2
     R6 =  (0.7-0.7)+(0.3-0.3)+(0.6-0.5)+(0.8-0.8)+(0.9-0.9)+(0.3-0.4)+(0.9-0.7)+(0.2-0.2)
     absolute  0    +   0     +   0.1   +   0     +   0     +   0.1     +   0.2 +   0
     result = 0.4


     R5 =  (0.7-0.7)+(0.3-0.9)+(0.6-0.1)+(0.8-0.9)+(0.9-0.4)+(0.3-0.2)+(0.9-0.2)+(0.2-0.2)
     absolute  0.0  +   0.6   +   0.5   +   0.1   +   0.5   +   0.1   +   0.7   +   0.0
     result = 2.5

     R2 =  (0.7-0.7)+(0.3-0.3)+(0.6-0.5)+(0.8-0.8)+(0.9-0.9)+(0.3-0.1)+(0.9-0.9)+(0.2-0.4)
     absolute  0.0  +   0.0   +   0.1   +   0.0   +   0.0   +   0.2   +   0.0   +   0.2
     result = 0.5
```

Comment: mysql to start with for testing but later may change to ms sql

Answer (score 1):

This should give you C1 values ordered ascending by your formula:

```
SELECT C1
FROM PERCENTAGES
ORDER BY ABS(C2 - 0.7) + ABS(C3 - 0.3) + ABS(C4 - 0.6) + ABS(C5 - 0.8) + 
         ABS(C6 - 0.9) + ABS(C7 - 0.3) + ABS(C8 - 0.9) + ABS(C9 - 0.2);
```

Tested with Oracle... but it's plain SQL that should work anywhere.
To get the top 3 values, you'll have to apply a DB-specific clause.

For MySQL it should be easy. Just add a `LIMIT 3` to the query.

I recommend to replace the constant input with variables and use a prepared statement to actually run the query. But that's a topic for another question.